# Using while true function allow multiple correct user input

Tags: python

I have used a while True function to allow a user to open a monthly excel file. Is there a way to allow a user to be able to open 12 other files that are monthly reports while still handling incorrect file choice?

```
while True:
    file = input("select file name: ")
    if not file == "July":
        file - input("unknown file, hit enter to select file name")
        continue
    else:
         df = pd.read_excel('filename here')
    break
```

Comment: `if file not in ["July", "August", ...]:`

Comment: Try to read the file inside `try/except/else`. If it succeeds, break out of the loop.

Comment: Would I use else for each file directory ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use os.path.exists to check that a file exists. Beyond that, there are other tests you might want to do - you might want to check the file extension, or make sure that it is in a particular directory, or whatever else correct user input means. If you're checking file extensions, you can do worse than to use pathlib.Path, which also has an exists() method.

Simple example with os.path.exists():

```
import os.path

while True:
    file = input("select file name: ")
    if not os.path.exists(file):
        file - input("File does not exist, hit enter to select file name")   
        continue
    else:
        df = pd.read_excel(file)
    break
```

You could make the code a lot more readable and concise if you put the conditional inside the while loop head (like Guido intended):

```
filename = input("select file name: ")
while not os.path.exists(filename):
    print("Error - file '%s' does not exist." % filename)
    filename = input("select file name: ")
df = pd.read_excel(filename)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understand, you can store all files' names in some variable and store all open files in another one. In this case, you need to break only when a user opened all 12 files.

Should be smth like this:

```
file_names = ("July", "August")
open_files = []
while True:
    file = input("select file name: ")
    if file not in file_names:
        input(
            "{file} - unknown file, hit enter to select file name".format(file)
        )
        continue
    elif file in open_files:
        file - input("{file} is already opened, try another one".format(file))
    else:
        df = pd.read_excel(file)
        open_files.append(file)

    if len(open_files) == 12:
        break
```